# Making API calls from DataStage 11.7 jobs scheduled in Control M

Tags: datastage

Is there any way to make API from DataStage to a source where the source has provided us the API link only. We need to make the API call to Source A and then create the job which will be called from Control M. Is this possible.

I am expecting to create and run DataStage jobs from Control M, making use of API call to fetch the source data.